# GetRawInputDeviceInfo returns wrong syntax of USB HID device name in Windows 10

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have a code that I found on the internet that uses the function GetRawInputDeviceInfo, but it doesn't get the name of the device right. sometimes it doesn't get a name at all. I've searched for an answer and found out that people had this problem on windows XP and windows 7 to. I am using windows 10 so that doesn't really help me.

[C++ - WinAPI get list of all connected USB devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453082/c-winapi-get-list-of-all-connected-usb-devices) (do i need to post the code itself? im new to stack overflow)

At the end of the day what I am trying to do is get the names of all the devices connected to my PC and print them out, but this function doesnt return the name of the mouse either, so if anyone has a suggestion on how to fix it or a better method to get the names Id'e love to hear you'r ideas. thanks in advance, -shon :)

EDIT2! the full code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

// Namespace
using namespace std;

// Main
int main()
{
    // Program
    cout << "USB Device Lister." << endl;

    // Get Number Of Devices
    UINT nDevices = 0;
    GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

    // Got Any?
    if (nDevices < 1)
    {
        // Exit
        cout << "ERR: 0 Devices?";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate Memory For Device List
    PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList;
    pRawInputDeviceList = new RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST) * nDevices];

    // Got Memory?
    if (pRawInputDeviceList == NULL)
    {
        // Error
        cout << "ERR: Could not allocate memory for Device List.";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    // Fill Device List Buffer
    int nResult;
    nResult = GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &nDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

    // Got Device List?
    if (nResult < 0)
    {
        // Clean Up
        delete[] pRawInputDeviceList;

        // Error
        cout << "ERR: Could not get device list.";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    std::set<std::string> DeviceList;
    // Loop Through Device List
    for (UINT i = 0; i < nDevices; i++)
    {
        // Get Character Count For Device Name
        UINT nBufferSize = 0;
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice, // Device
            RIDI_DEVICENAME,                // Get Device Name
            NULL,                           // NO Buff, Want Count!
            &nBufferSize);                 // Char Count Here!

                                           // Got Device Name?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
            // Error
            cout << "ERR: Unable to get Device Name character count.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

            // Next
            continue;
        }

        // Allocate Memory For Device Name
        WCHAR* wcDeviceName = new WCHAR[nBufferSize + 1];

        // Got Memory
        if (wcDeviceName == NULL)
        {
            // Error
            cout << "ERR: Unable to allocate memory for Device Name.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

            // Next
            continue;
        }

        // Get Name
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice, // Device
            RIDI_DEVICENAME,                // Get Device Name
            wcDeviceName,                   // Get Name!
            &nBufferSize);                 // Char Count

                                           // Got Device Name?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
            // Error
            cout << "ERR: Unable to get Device Name.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

            // Clean Up
            delete[] wcDeviceName;

            // Next
            continue;
        }

        // Set Device Info & Buffer Size
        RID_DEVICE_INFO rdiDeviceInfo;
        rdiDeviceInfo.cbSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
        nBufferSize = rdiDeviceInfo.cbSize;

        // Get Device Info
        nResult = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInputDeviceList[i].hDevice,
            RIDI_DEVICEINFO,
            &rdiDeviceInfo,
            &nBufferSize);

        // Got All Buffer?
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
            // Error
            cout << "ERR: Unable to read Device Info.. Moving to next device." << endl << endl;

            // Next
            continue;
        }

        // Mouse
        if (rdiDeviceInfo.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
        {
            // Current Device
            int id = rdiDeviceInfo.mouse.dwId; //device id
            string s = "ID: " + std::to_string(id) + ", Type : MOUSE"; //device type is mouse
            DeviceList.insert(s);
        }

        // Keyboard
        else if (rdiDeviceInfo.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
        {
        // Current Device
        cout << endl << "Displaying device " << i + 1 << " information. (KEYBOARD)" << endl;
        wcout << L"Name " << wcDeviceName << endl; //*Problem is here!* //
        cout << "Keyboard mode: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwKeyboardMode << endl;
        cout << "Number of function keys: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfFunctionKeys << endl;
        cout << "Number of indicators: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfIndicators << endl;
        cout << "Number of keys total: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal << endl;
        cout << "Type of the keyboard: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwType << endl;
        cout << "Subtype of the keyboard: " << rdiDeviceInfo.keyboard.dwSubType << endl;
        }

        // Some HID
        else // (rdi.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID)
        {
        // Current Device
        cout << endl << "Displaying device " << i + 1 << " information. (HID)" << endl;
        wcout << L"Device Name: " << wcDeviceName << endl;
        cout << "Vendor Id:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwVendorId << endl;
        cout << "Product Id:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwProductId << endl;
        cout << "Version No:" << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.dwVersionNumber << endl;
        cout << "Usage for the device: " << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.usUsage << endl;
        cout << "Usage Page for the device: " << rdiDeviceInfo.hid.usUsagePage << endl;
        } 

        // Delete Name Memory!
        delete[] wcDeviceName;
    }

    // Clean Up - Free Memory
    delete[] pRawInputDeviceList;

    for (std::set<string>::iterator i = DeviceList.begin(); i != DeviceList.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
    // Exit
    cout << endl << "Finnished.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, a [mcve] is required, alongside a succinct problem statement, including the expected behavior as well as the observed behavior. See [ask].

Comment: You are not assigning or filling `wcDeviceName` anywhere. Maybe there is missing code you didn't post?

Comment: Maybe you are compiling a non-Unicode program? So you are calling `GetRawInputDeviceInfoA()`, not `GetRawInputDeviceInfoW()`, with a `WCHAR` array?

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be *minimal*. And you still haven't provided a proper problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows there are two flavors of API calls: Unicode and ANSI. The former takes and returns UTF-16 encoded Unicode strings; the latter takes and returns 8-bit encoded strings (the exact encoding depends on the OS localization).

You choose which flavor you want to use by #defining (or not #defining) the macro `UNICODE`. Depending on that the function changes name, with an `W` or `A` suffix.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetRawInputDeviceInfo GetRawInputDeviceInfoW
#else
#define GetRawInputDeviceInfo GetRawInputDeviceInfoA
#endif
```

All the structures that may contain text data are also duplicated with the `W` or `A` suffixes.

Now your problem: you are not defining `UNICODE` so you are actually calling `GetRawInputDeviceInfoA()`, the ANSI flavor, that expects a `char*`, but you are passing a `WCHAR*`, that is a UNICODE string!

The solution is easy:

```
char* wcDeviceName = new char[nBufferSize + 1];
```

It is unfortunate that this function `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()` has its arguments overloaded, so it is declared as taking a `void*`, so the compiler cannot catch the error. If you were calling a simpler function, say `SetWindowText()` then you would have got a compiler error because of incompatible pointer type.

If you really want the full UNICODE name of the device, you may prefer keep the `WCHAR` string and then call the UNICODE function specifically:

```
WCHAR* wcDeviceName = new WCHAR[nBufferSize + 1];
...
GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(..., RIDI_DEVICENAME, wcDeviceName, ...);
```