# Detect if exe is running from a USB

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am writing an app using windows API that needs to check on startup that it is running from a USB device.
What I have achieved so far

- List devices using SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo
- Detecting which device is removable

Here is my code to do the above 2 tasks

```
HDEVINFO hdevinfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE,NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);
if (hdevinfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    WriteLog(L"hdevinfo is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
    return USB_PROT_ERROR;
}
DWORD MemberIndex = 0;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA sp_devinfo_data;
ZeroMemory(&sp_devinfo_data, sizeof(sp_devinfo_data));
sp_devinfo_data.cbSize = sizeof(sp_devinfo_data);
while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hdevinfo, MemberIndex, &sp_devinfo_data)) {
    DWORD PropertyRegDataType;
    DWORD RequiredSize;
    TCHAR PropertyBuffer[500];
    //get the name of this device
    if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hdevinfo, &sp_devinfo_data, SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME, &PropertyRegDataType, (PBYTE)&PropertyBuffer, sizeof(PropertyBuffer), &RequiredSize)) {
        WriteLog(L"Device name: %s", PropertyBuffer);
        DWORD PropertyValue;
        //get removal policy for this device
        if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hdevinfo, &sp_devinfo_data, SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY, &PropertyRegDataType, (PBYTE)&PropertyValue, sizeof(PropertyValue), &RequiredSize)) {
            if (PropertyValue == CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL) {
                //not removable
                WriteLog(L"Not Removable");
            }
            else {
                //removable
                WriteLog("Removable");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my PC with 1 HARD DRIVE and 1 USB DRIVE attached, I get this output:

```
Device name: \Device\00000031
Not Removable

Device name: \Device\00000070
Removable
```

From the output it is clear that **\Device\00000070** is my USB device. And from My Computer I can see that my USB device is mounted on **H** drive

What I want to achieve now is

- Find out that on which drive letter (in my case it is **H:**) that removable device (in my case it is **\Device\00000070**) is mounted.

**OR**

- Find out all the volumes(sub devices I can say) that are under this device. For example if I pass GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME GUID to SetupDiGetClassDevs function then my output looks like this:

  Device name: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
  **Not Removable**

  Device name: \Device\HarddiskVolume4
  **Not Removable**

  Device name: \Device\HarddiskVolume9
  **Not Removable**

  Device name: \Device\HarddiskVolume5
  **Not Removable**

After some debugging I found that ***\Device\HarddiskVolume9*** is my USB but you can see in the output that it always show **"Not Removable"**. So if I can find out that ***\Device\HarddiskVolume9*** belongs to **\Device\00000070** then that will also work for me as I can then easily use Volume management functions to find the drive letter for **\Device\HarddiskVolume9** and match with the drive letter of the executable.

***I want to do this using C/C++ Windows API without using any 3rd party library and no .NET code.***

Comment: Consider this function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew

Comment: @armagedescu ... thank you ...but I used this function and it returns the following
**\Device\HarddiskVolume9\PROJECTS\UsbProtector\Debug\Protector.exe**
which is correct because \Device\HarddiskVolume9 is my USB. But the problem is what I mentioned in my question that \Device\HarddiskVolume9 always says "Not removable" which means I cannot know whether it is a USB or not. Thanks

Comment: @RameezUsmani this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456067/5878272

Comment: I assume you first find out from which path is the exe running from (ex. e:\\mysoftware.exe), then you want to know if e:\ is a usb device?

Comment: @RameezUsmani There must exist another function, maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew is also referred in link I've given in first comment

Comment: Be careful: `H:\PROJECTS` does not have to be on the same device as `H:\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API function [GetDriveType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) returns the following:

**DRIVE_UNKNOWN** - 0 - The drive type cannot be determined.

**DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR** - 1 - The root path is invalid; for example, there is no volume mounted at the specified path.

**DRIVE_REMOVABLE** - 2 - The drive has removable media; for example, a floppy drive, thumb drive, or flash card reader.

**DRIVE_FIXED** - 3 - The drive has fixed media; for example, a hard disk drive or flash drive.

**DRIVE_REMOTE** - 4 - The drive is a remote (network) drive.

**DRIVE_CDROM** - 5 - The drive is a CD-ROM drive.

**DRIVE_RAMDISK** - 6 - The drive is a RAM disk.

So I would use the following code, checking if the return value is equal to (2) - Removable:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    wchar_t basePath[1024]{ L"" }, volName[1024]{ L"" };
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, basePath, 1024);
    GetVolumePathName(basePath, volName, 1024);

    UINT type = GetDriveType(volName);
    if (type == 2)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"You are running from a flash drive (USB)",L"",MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"You are NOT running from a flash drive (USB)",L"", MB_OK);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...this function i already tried but i was testing with my external usb hard drive and windows was returning it as DRIVE_FIXED .... After your answer I tried with my usb flash drive and it returned DRIVE_REMOVABLE for that...
damn it took me so many hours .....thanks a lot

Comment: `argv[0]` is undefined. here can be any. need use `GetModuleFileNameW` for example, if need path to exe

Comment: also your code anyway wrong. `GetDriveType`wait for *trailing backslash*. you not add it to path

Comment: @RbMm - I changed the code to use GetModuleFileName and I am now including the trailing backslash in the drive letter to check.

Comment: That `basePath[3] = L'\0';` should be a call to `GetVolumePathName`

Comment: @BenVoigt - good advice! I updated the source code accordingly.

Comment: `GetVolumePathName` not need at all

Comment: @RbMm: Of course it is needed, unless you want the function to fail on computers that use mount points.

Comment: @BenVoigt - and how mount point here create problem ? when we open device by name - we open final (real) device object, even if we go via symbolick links (almost always) and file system mount points. and finally we(ok *GetDriveType*) call *ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile* with *FileFsDeviceInformation* and got `FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION` structure .

Comment: @RbMm: Do you mean to pass the entire path to `GetDriveType`?  That may work, although it clearly violates the contract which says that you must pass in a root directory.  The code as-written before I suggested `GetVolumePathName` pulled just the drive letter, which will form a root directory but potentially on the completely wrong device.

Comment: @BenVoigt - i just for test create mount point on removable device (point to fixed disk) - and call `GetDriveType` on such mount point path return correct result `DRIVE_FIXED`. and visa versa - if create mount point on fixed drive with final path - to removable - we got `DRIVE_REMOVABLE` as expected.

Comment: @RbMm: "call `GetDriveType` on such mount point path".. exactly!  To get the mount point path the `GetVolumePathName` function is used.

Comment: @BenVoigt - no, you not understand me. may be because my very bad english. i not use `GetVolumePathName` and it not need. really `GetDriveType` work on **any** device path with ended by \ symbol (and this need only because api check for this). ok, this is  **clearly violates the contract** - but this api work not only for  root directory, but for **any** device pat with any form (only path must be valid). i be of course not use this api at all. but call `CreateFileW` (or `NtOpenFile`) and than direct call `ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile` with `FileFsDeviceInformation`

Comment: in any case `GetVolumePathName` not need and result will be correct - noi matter exist symlinks/mount points in path or nor. exist it or not - we open device to which mountpoint point and query this device attributes

Comment: @RbMm: Most probably Microsoft will never fix their bug and begin to return `DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR` as their documentation promises, but if they do, my suggestion using `GetVolumePathName` then `GetDriveType` will still work.  And `CreateFile` then `ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile` will also work (although undocumented).  But `GetDriveType` without `GetVolumePathName` is not guaranteed to always succeed, and according to the documentation it should result in `DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - are you know really when `GetDriveType` return `DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR` ? this is funny, but when string not containing trailing backslash as last symbol. so this is really based only on string manipulation ! not related to real root path or not. however i be use this code - https://pastebin.com/NFZ8XBTM.

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, it clearly is a bug and does not return that value under the conditions that the documentation says (when the input path is not a volume root directory).

Comment: @BenVoigt - honesty say i in self code never use `GetDriveType` at all but always use [*ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-zwqueryvolumeinformationfile) with [*FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_fs_device_information) and check `bRemovable = (ffdi.Characteristics & FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA) != 0 ;`